# Retrieving data from mysql using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to retrieve some data from an SQL table using JDBC through the `BufferedReader`, the code I wrote for this execution:

```
System.out.println("Type a name");
    String nname = br.readLine();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/VetTest", "root", "root");
        Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from Pet WHERE name LIKE '?%'";
        ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) 
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));

        if (petn.equals(query)) {
        System.out.println("Searching names.." + nname + query);
        }
```

I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, so to summarize my question, I'm trying to retrieve some data depend about what the user inputs in the console. E.g. I'm trying to search for the name Jack in my database I want my application to search for this person's name or a similar person name.

The result I always get when I enter a petname (even though the pet the name is available in my database):

No such a name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't told us what the problem was, but I see one problem:

```
WHERE name LIKE '?%'
```

That is incorrect. The clause should be

```
WHERE name LIKE ?
```

and you should prepare a statement, bind a string containing the wildcard (`%`), and then execute this prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from Pet WHERE name LIKE ?");
stmt.setString(1, name + "%");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Read [the tutorial about prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: my problem is i can't figure out a way to make the bufferedreader to check the names (in the database and the one user inputs in the console)

Comment: I can't make any sense of your comment. What are you trying to achieve? Explain it as if I was a 5-year old boy. The user is in front of the computer. What should happen?

Comment: Sorry my english isn't great, well what I'm trying to achieve is when the user enters for example a name in the console, I want my application to check if the name is available in the database or not.

Comment: Then execute the query, and if its result set is not empty, then the database contains a pet with that name. If it's empty, then it doesn't contain a pet with that name. `rs.next()` will return false if the result set is empty. If you want an exact match with the entered name, you shouldn't use `like` and a wildcard, but `=`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I still feel kinda lost, I added this method and still no result: if (rs.next()) {
    petn = rs.getString("petname");
    System.out.println("test" + petn);
   }

Comment: the application is still not checking whether the name i enter in the console through the bufferedreader is exist or not.

Comment: If you get no output, it means that there is no pet with that name in the database. Add an `else` clause: `else { System.out.println("No pet with the name " + name + " in the database); }`. You should master if/else clauses, and be able to add traces in your code to see what happens before using JDBC. And you should also learn to use a debugger. Edit your question, and add the complete current code of your program. It's hard to tell if it's wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Just edited it! I'm pretty sure that I have the name stored in my database, yet I still get name isn't available. Thanks.

Comment: That's far from being the complete code of the program. And I don't see any trace of what the user actually typed as a name. Maybe there's a hidden space at the beginning or end of the name. You won't know for sure without adding traces to your code of using a debugger.

Comment: After I traced my code, I think the part that is not working is "petn = rs.getString("petname");" where petn is bufferedReader name and the petname is the column name in my database. I don't really know what to use instead of that to lookup for the specified name in my database.

Comment: This instruction is inside the `if` block which is **not** executed (since the `else` block **is** executed). So I don't see how it could be the problem.

Comment: I don't really know why it isn't checking if the name is available in the database, yes you're right. But the if (rs.next()) should be .equals()? Because it's checking if it's equals to the one I inputted in the console through the bufferedReader.

Comment: I can't understand your comment at all. Why don't you put the whole code in your question as asked, with the traces, and the output you got?

Comment: Do you realize that your code doesn't do what my answer tells you to do at all? What's the point in answering your question if you don't take it into account? Your JDBC code is completely wrong. I answered with the code you should use, but you still use your old, wrong code. I give up, sorry.

Comment: I'm so so sorry to bother you, I was trying to working but im still having an error and i tried to debug it, and I figured out the error and now it's working perfectly! Thank you so much, that really help and sorry for bothering you again :) have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong u wanted to search name which could be a part in some other names also.
For example if u type Jack

The values of Jackson,Helen Jack should also be retrieved from database.Then change the query as

```
System.out.println("Type a name");
    String nname = br.readLine();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/VetTest", "root", "root");
        Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        **String query = "select * from Pet WHERE name LIKE '%nname%'";**
        ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) 
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));

        if (petn.equals(query)) {
        System.out.println("Searching names.." + nname + query);
        }
```